# Sort object using inner objects property

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class called `Class` and which is having a students property of type `Set<Student>`. I want to sort based on the collection of students `Set<Student>`

```
public class Class {
    private int id;
    private String className;
    private Set<Student> students;
    //getter an setter here
}

public class Student {
    private int id; 
    private String name;
    private int age;
   //getter an setter here
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear? Please explain the usecase properly.

Comment: If you want to sort collection of classes based on set of students it still would need some more defined rule about which class comes first? The one with most students, the one with oldest average age of students, the one with most students with names starting with "J" or what?

Comment: Please also add what you have tried so far to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `Comparator` ([See API here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) for objects of class `Class`. Here is an example where the comparator will sort your classes by increasing size of their `students` property:

```
class ClassComparator implements Comparator<Class> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Class o1, Class o2) {
        int set1Size = o1.getStudents().size();
        int set2Size = o2.getStudents().size();
        return Integer.compare(set1Size, set2Size);
    }
}
```

You only need to implement the `compare` method. Simply change the algorithm to fit your requirement, here is what it is supposed to return (taken from the API doc)

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Then you use it this way

```
List<Class> classes = ... // your list of Classes
classes.sort(new ClassComparator());
```

This will sort the `classes` List

Comment: You’re performing unnecessary and avoidable boxing in the compare method. A better option would be to use Integer#compare.

Comment: @Aominè indeed, I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to sort by the number of students in each class.

In which case a simple solution would be as follows:

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((Class c) -> c.getStudents().size()));
```